# How do I attach a condition to a random choice?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, random

I would like choice 5 to be presented if the child is on the naughty list, but choice 6 to be presented for nice list.  My problem is allocation to a list is a random choice of tuple values.

```
import random, time # allowing use of random and delays
choice=[
'eddie',
'dan',
'erin',
'josh',
]

choices2=[
'naughty list',
'nice list'
]

choices3=[
'merry xmas anyhoooo!',
'cannot win them all!',
'have fun dude!',
'man\'s not got?',
]

choices4=[
'must have been when you pushed the granny over',
'could have been that cookie you stole?!',
'probably because you were cheeky to a teacher'
]

choices5=[
'must be because you are an angel',
'must be because you keep your room tidy',
'Santa just never saw you'
]
while True:
    input('\npress enter to check who is on the list')
    print('checking...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(random.choice(choice))
    time.sleep(2)

    print(random.choice(choices2))
    if random.choice =='naughty list':
        print(random.choice(choices4))
    elif choices2=='nice list':
        print(random.choice(choices5))
    else:
        print('wrong')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(random.choice(choices3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code :

```
 import random, time # allowing use of random and delays
choice1=[
'eddie',
'dan',
'erin',
'josh',
]

choices2=[
'naughty list',
'nice list'
]

choices3=[
'merry xmas anyhoooo!',
'cannot win them all!',
'have fun dude!',
'man\'s not got?',
]

choices4=[
'must have been when you pushed the granny over',
'could have been that cookie you stole?!',
'probably because you were cheeky to a teacher'
]

choices5=[
'must be because you are an angel',
'must be because you keep your room tidy',
'Santa just never saw you'
]
while True:
    input('\npress enter to check who is on the list')
    print('checking...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(random.choice(choice1))
    time.sleep(2)

    list1 = random.choice(choices2)
    print(list1)
    if list1 =='naughty list':
        print(random.choice(choices4))
    elif list1=='nice list':
        print(random.choice(choices5))
    else:
        print('wrong')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(random.choice(choices3))
```

Also, choice is a being used internally by the random function so changed the list name to choice1

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this :-(